# Lower hrulefill inside tabu

Tags: rules, tabu

I'm trying to make a paper form.  I want to draw a horizontal line for people to write on.  I want that line below the baseline.  I found [a TUGboat on making forms](https://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb24-2/tb77wilson.pdf) that defines an `\xfill` command that works fine in a paragraph, but I can't get it to work in a `tabu` environment.  How can I use position something equivalent to `\hrulefill` below the baseline in a `tabu` environment?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% From https://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb24-2/tb77wilson.pdf
\newcommand*{\xfill}[1][0pt]{%
  \cleaders
  \hbox to 1pt{\hss
    \raisebox{#1}{\rule{1.2pt}{0.4pt}}%
    \hss}\hfill}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

This works: \xfill[-0.5ex]

\begin{tabu}{@{}X@{}}
  Rule is too high: \hrulefill \\
  Rule is not visible: \xfill[-0.5ex] \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Rendered:

[image: Rendered MWE]

I'm using MacTeX 2014, rendering with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`xhfill`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xhfill) package which gives commands that extend `\hrulefill` allowing you to control the attributes (color, thickness, height/depth):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}

% From https://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb24-2/tb77wilson.pdf
\newcommand*{\xfill}[1][0pt]{%
  \cleaders
  \hbox to 1pt{\hss
    \raisebox{#1}{\rule{1.2pt}{0.4pt}}%
    \hss}\hfill}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

This works: \xfill[-0.5ex]

\begin{tabu}{@{}X@{}}
  Rule is too high: \hrulefill \\
  Rule is visible: \xrfill[-0.5ex]{0.4pt} \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you want to use `\xrfill` in a table cell by itself, you seem to need to `\leavevmode` first (e.g. `\leavevmode\xrfill{0.4pt}`).  Without `\leavevmode` you get "Leaders not followed by proper glue."